# Does a counterspelled spell still trigger the Mage Slayer feat's reaction attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, spellcasting, counterspelling

*Counterspell* states:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell. If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its spell fails and has no effect.

This wording suggests that a successful *counterspell* interrupts the spell, causing it to fail.

The Mage Slayer feat (PHB, p. 168) states:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you casts a spell, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against that creature.

This text seems to say that you only get the attack if the creature finishes casting the spell.

**If a spell is counterspelled, does it still count as a spell cast for the purpose of Mage Slayer's reaction attack?**

The answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86783/does-a-countered-spell-cost-a-spell-slot) seem to suggest yes, but unlike many other interrupts, *counterspell* does actually prevent the spell from being cast, so it's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes.

The important part is in the description for *counterspell*:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of
>   casting a spell. If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd
>   level or lower, **its spell fails** and has no effect.

Emphasis added by me to point out that you aren't preventing the spell from occurring with *counterspell*- you are preventing it from *succeeding*.  The action is still used, the spell slot is still gone- and Mage Slayer doesn't care whether the spell actually works, you can still attack as a reaction.

Comment: Interestingly the casting of counter spell itself would trigger Mage Slayer if there was an enemy with the feat within 5' of the person casting counter spell.