# If an Eldritch Knight's cantrip is counterspelled, can they still make a bonus-action weapon attack from the War Magic feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, counterspelling, eldritch-knight

The [Eldritch Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight)'s [War Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#WarMagic-222) feature (PHB, pg. 75) states:

> Beginning at 7th level, when you use your **action to cast** a cantrip, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action.

(The 18th-level [Improved War Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ImprovedWarMagic-225) feature works the same way, but allows any spell as your action rather than being limited to cantrips.)

The description of [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) states:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in **the process of casting a spell**. If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its spell fails and has no effect. If it is casting a spell of 4th level or higher, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a success, the creature's spell fails and has no effect.

For example, say my Eldritch Knight attempts to cast *booming blade*. If someone casts *counterspell* on my *booming blade*, am I still able to make the bonus-action weapon attack?

Comment: Related: [Does a counterspelled spell still trigger the Mage Slayer feat's reaction attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/does-a-counterspelled-spell-still-trigger-the-mage-slayer-feats-reaction-attack)

Comment: Does the given answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 32):

### Since you used the action, you still make the attack

The ability specifically says that when you use your action to cast the spell, you get to use the BA attack. Counter spell is cast in reaction to a spell being cast and causes it to have no effect. Since counterspell doesn't cause the casting to fail, simply the spell being cast, you **still used your action to cast a spell**. As such, according to the ability, you'd still get your attack

Comment: In other words - what gets you the BA Attack isn't _casting_ the spell, but _"paying" the action to do so_.

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I'm saying/ Since it says it activates upon using the action to cast a spell, what triggers it is simply using the action in that way

Comment: I do believe this logic is correct, though I am curious whether this matches the designer intent... [TheVagrantDog's answer to the question "Does a counterspelled spell still trigger the Mage Slayer feat's reaction attack?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107631/33569) agrees with your logic, saying, "you aren't preventing the spell from occurring with *counterspell*- you are preventing it from *succeeding*."