# Is a slowed spellcaster counterspellable on other people's turns until he finishes casting on his next turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

One of the effects of the [*slow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell is particularly nasty for spellcasting targets:

> If the creature casts a spell with a time of 1 action, roll a d20. On an 11 or higher, the spell can't take effect until the creature's next turn, and the creature must use its action on that turn to ***complete the spell***. If it can't, the spell is wasted.

The [*counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) spell says:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature ***that you can see casting a spell***.

Let's say Bob the Evil Wizard gets *slow*ed, then tries to cast a spell but rolls an 11+ on the die, and is therefore only able to complete his spell on his next turn. In the meanwhile, it becomes Tom the Nice Wizard's turn.

**Can Tom *counterspell* Bob on his own turn in that situation, considering that Bob is still in the process of casting his spell?**

Answer (score 20):

## Yes, you can counterspell while the spellcaster is still casting

[Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) only requires the following for it's Reaction trigger:

> *which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell*

In the case you've outlined, the spell is still being cast so it meets that requirement. As long as you have your Reaction available, you can take that on your turn to use Counterspell.

See this [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86783/does-a-countered-spell-cost-a-spell-slot) discussing counterspelling a longer casting time.