# Formulas from Petersen's Cthulhu Mythos - can they be Counterspelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, counterspelling, cthulhu-mythos

Formulas in [Sandy Petersen's *Cthulhu Mythos*](https://petersengames.com/the-games-shop/cthulhu-mythos-for-5e/) are similar to Rituals with a few key differences. Like Rituals they can be cast without a spell slot, and you can also use spells slots to cast them (generally more quickly, or potentially at a higher level). Unlike Rituals Formulas require Skill checks to cast, carry penalties for failure (and sometimes success), and can be cast by anyone, even non-casters.

The fluff around formulas contains the following:

> Such a spell draws upon universal principles that allow
> them to function even for non-spellcasters. Formula
> magic uses science and mathematics beyond most mortal
> understanding to power the casting of highly specialized
> spells. Most formulas are held only in shunned books and
> in the minds of dangerous eccentrics who know more than
> is safe about the secrets of reality. Generally, these spells
> depend upon knowledge of the alien sciences, extradimensional mathematics, and incomprehensible iconography of
> the cosmic forces underlying the Mythos.

The [consensus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131906/when-can-you-counterspell-a-spell-with-long-casting-time) seems to be that Rituals are able to be counterspelled at any time during their casting; I don't see a reason why Formulas would necessarily be different, but there are enough differences that I'm left unsure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, they are still spells and are still cast

All throughout the chapter *Formulas* are still referred to as spells:

> Certain **spells** in this chapter have a special tag:formula. Such a **spell** draws upon universal principles (…).

> Generally, these **spells** depend upon knowledge of the alien sciences, extradimensional mathematics and incomprehensible iconography (…).

Casting as  formula is still **casting a spell**:

> A spell with the formula tag **can be cast normally**, [or] **as a formula** (…).

> **Casting a spell as a formula** takes the normal casting time (…).

> Formula spells can be learned and **cast** by anyone with the appropriate tools and knowledge.

> Even character without the Spellcasting feature or Pact Magic feature can learn and **cast spells** as formulas.

These is just a few examples but the same wording is used anytime Formulas are referred to, this leads me to believe they are intended to be treated as regular spells for the purpose of Counterspell.