# If somebody Counterspells a Counterspell, is the original spell cast successfully?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, counterspelling

Assume Caster A casts **fireball**.

Assume Caster B casts **counterspell** on A's fireball using his reaction.

Now Caster A can use **his reaction** and also cast counterspell on Caster B's counterspell.

Does this mean that Caster A can finally cast **fireball** and B can do nothing about it?

Or does this mean that Caster B can cast another **counterspell** to counter Caster A's **counterspell** attempt?

This gets out of hand so I described it as simple as I could. I hope I get an answer because I was on a dispute with one of my players for this mechanic.

Answer (score 24):

### Yes, the original spell will take effect

Counterspell has no restrictions on what spell it can counter (beyond the possible ability check for higher level spells).

It states that the...

> spell fails and has no effect.

So if a Counterspell is, in turn, countered, it will have no effect.

If that Counterspell has no effect then it was not able to counter the original spell!

With only two casters this is as far as it can possibly go of course, because each caster only has 1 reaction. More casters = more possible reactions so it could indeed get very silly, though in practice it seems doubtful you would have so many casters about who also have that spell prepared!

Comment: So if the fireball get's countered by a counterspell, and the counterspell is countered by fireball's caster counterspell, does this mean that the original caster is then able to cast fireball?

Comment: It would be good to quote the rule about how play continues after a reaction is resolved: "If the reaction interrupts another creature's turn, that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction."

Comment: And this is why my prime counterspeller characters always have sorcerer... a Subtle Counterspell has no visible components, and therefore cannot be Counterspelled itself.

Comment: @T.J.L. Or you simply cast from an item :) for the same reason.

Comment: @Slagmoth I was more talking about ending the potential counter-counter-counter chain early. I generally don't use Subtle Spell in combat for anything but counterspell (it has non-combat uses, of course). Unfortunately, beyond loading a single instance into a *Ring of Spell Storing*, I can't think of any official item that would let you cast *Counterspell*. :(

Comment: @T.J.L. I get that, I was more talking about casting a spell like fireball from an item since it doesn't have anything perceivable either, but your example and use is more plausible in most situations.

Comment: It might be worth noting that as far as the developers of the game were concerned, you don't actually know what spells other people are casting unless you use your reaction to identify them, as per Xanathar. So it's perfectly possible to go: "A casts a spell while pointing at B!" - "B starts casting a spell in response!" - "A: Oh no he's counterspelling, quick counterspell it!" - "C casts counterspell on B, who was in fact casting a different reaction spell.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, provided you have a Reaction available.

The [*Counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) description says (emphasis mine)

> You attempt to **interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell**.
> If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its spell
> fails and has no effect. If it is casting a spell of 4th level or
> higher, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC
> equals 10 + the spell's level. On a success, the creature's spell
> fails and has no effect.

Under "Casting Time", the PHB (pag 202) says (emphasis mine)

> Some spells can be cast as reactions. These spells take a fraction of
> a second to bring about and *are cast in response to some event*.

Hence, the steps are the following:

- Caster A casts a spell.
- While A is doing the magic (moving hands, chanting, et cetera), caster B casts *Counterspell*. Suppose that B has success.
- If A still has its Reaction available, they can cast *Counterspell* for trying to nullify B's *Counterspell*. If A has no Reaction available, they can not cast it.

Let's consider the following case:

- (a) A casts 3rd level *Fireball*.
- (b) B uses their reaction and casts 3rd level *Counterspell*: in this way, A's *Fireball* would be successfully counterspelled.
- (c) A has their reaction available: they cast *Counterspell* vs B's, which is hence nullified by A's, who can keep on casting *Fireball* with success.

Suppose now that in (b) B casts *Counterspell* at 4th level and in (c) A casts it at 3rd level: by the rules of the spell, an ability check is required (DC 14, in this case). If A wins, then B's *Counterspell* is nullified and then A resorts to its *Fireball* casting, while if A loses B's *Counterspell* nullifies A's *Fireball*.

This very scenario is depicted in the latest version of the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA161):

> **Can you cast a reaction spell on your turn?**
>
> You sure can! Here’s a common way for it to happen: Cornelius the wizard is casting fireball on his turn, and his foe casts counterspell on him. Cornelius also has counterspell prepared, so he uses his reaction to cast it and break his foe’s counterspell before it can stop fireball.

---

***Or does this mean that Caster B can cast another counterspell to counter Caster A's counterspell attempt?***: No, because B has only 1 reaction per turn that had already been used for casting the first *Counterspell*.

---

Under a role-play point of view, we can see the *Counterspell* as just one (or more) gesture(s) that ruins the manipulation of the Wave by a caster. Using *Counterspell* against another *Counterspell* during a spell casting is possible (just add a simple gesture to the casting), and it can be seen as the two casters battling for mastering the Wave.

Comment: I honestly can't tell what your conclusion is.

Comment: @NautArch My conclusion is that you can use *Counterspell* againts a *Counterspell* while casting another spell: You are right, I've written an unclear answer, and there is not final conclusion: let me rewrite it.

Comment: It seems like you are answering if you can cast a counterspell, not if the initial spell is stopped, but I may be misreading.

Comment: @NautArch What I intended is that if you have counterspell prepared and a reaction available, you can cast counterspell and if you have success then the original spell (the fireball, in OP's case) is cast successfully. I missed maybe the second point of OP question "Caster B can cast another counterspell to counter Caster A's counterspell attempt?": I will add this.

Answer (score -5):

[PJRZ's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/163052/30798) is correct per rules as written. The exact exchange of spells described here is specifically cited as a legal example in the Sage Advice Compendium.

I assert that the rules as written are bad and wrong.

The legal target of Counterspell is "a creature in the process of Casting a Spell." The original caster has not finished casting the original spell when the counter caster starts casting Counterspell, or they would not be a legal target. In order for the original caster to cast Counterspell on the Counterspell, therefore, one of the following must be true:

1. You can be casting two spells at the same time.
2. You can stop the process of casting a spell, do something else, and then resume and successfully complete the casting.

I assert that both of these are inconsistent with the image of spellcasting produced by the rest of the rules text.

1. Spells have casting times, as well as verbal, somatic, and material components unique to the spell. The rules are generally explicit about which things you can do at the same time, and there is no indication that spells are an exception.
2. The rules on spells with a casting time of more than one turn state:

   > When you Cast a Spell with a Casting Time longer than a single action or Reaction, you must spend your action each turn casting the spell [...] If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over.

Counter-countering does violence to the imagination in much the same way that the peasant railgun does, and that is reason enough for me to suggest excluding it, the rules authors notwithstanding.

Comment: Related on [counterspelling a counterspell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62217/counterspelling-a-counterspell). That may change your view or you can try a different answer to that one and see what the response is.

Comment: It doesn't change my view, as I still think the counter-counter is *straight nonsense* in the sense that I cannot imagine what the original caster is doing to make this work, but the rules citations are specific and clear in contradicting my position. I will add them to my answer and let the votes fall as they may.

Comment: Or this answer can be deleted as attempting to reject the valid premise of the question and thus not being an answer to it. This is not the hill I want to die on.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your objection is to the example situation where A casts, B counters, and A counter-counters (while in the process of casting the original spell). The essence of the question, however, is to ask whether counterspell can itself be countered; who casts the counter-counter isn't important. The second counter could be performed by a third caster, C, in which case your "you can only cast one spell at a time" objection is no longer relevant.